# Trying to loop to format data for graphing

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I've been working on this for a bit, and I've just come to a roadblock. I'm trying to format some data for graphing in Excel, and it looks like this:
[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsfFc.png)
I'd like to have the output look like this:
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibR6K.png)
The actual number of faults and days vary wildly, so it has to be open-ended, so it can do a full search of the imported file. I'm trying to do it using VBA without relying on a formula.
Let me know if there's anything I could be doing different.

Here's the code:

```
Sub Graph()

Dim GraphDataWS, DataWS, FormWS As Worksheet
Dim criteria1, InspectedMtr As String
Dim totalrow, ErrorRangevar, DateRangeVar, Row1, Col1 As Long
Dim Daterange, ErrorRange As Range
Dim criteria2 As Variant
Dim ErrorCount, Output As Double

Worksheets("Graph Data").Activate

Set Worksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Graph Data")

Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.ClearContents

Set GraphDataWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Graph Data")
Set FormWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Formulas")
Set DataWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

totalrow = FormWS.Range("A21").Value

Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:A" & totalrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy (Worksheets("Graph Data").Range("B1"))
Worksheets("Data").Range("E1:E" & totalrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy (Worksheets("Graph Data").Range("A1"))

With GraphDataWS
ErrorRangevar = GraphDataWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
GraphDataWS.Range("A1:A" & ErrorRangevar).Copy (GraphDataWS.Range("C1:C" & ErrorRangevar))
GraphDataWS.Range("C2:C" & ErrorRangevar).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1
DateRangeVar = GraphDataWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
GraphDataWS.Range("B1:B" & DateRangeVar).Copy (GraphDataWS.Range("D1:D" & DateRangeVar))
GraphDataWS.Range("D2:D" & DateRangeVar).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1

'DateRangeVar = GraphDataWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row

Range("D2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("E1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


ErrorRangevar = ErrorRangevar + 2

Worksheets("Graph Data").Activate
Output = 0

Set Daterange = GraphDataWS.Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(1, DateRangeVar))
Set ErrorRange = GraphDataWS.Range("C1:C" & ErrorRangevar)

For a = 2 To ErrorRangevar

criteria1 = Cells(a, 3).Value

For b = 2 To ErrorRangevar

criteria2 = Cells(a, 4).Value


For i = 2 To ErrorRangevar
        If ((Cells(i, 1)) = criteria1) And (Cells(i, 2) = criteria2) Then
            Output = Output + 1
        End If
Next i

Row1 = ErrorRange.Find(What:=criteria1).Row
Col1 = Daterange.Find(What:=criteria2).Column


Cells(Row1, Col1).Value = Output

MsgBox criteria1 & " " & Row1 & " " & criteria2 & " " & Col1 & " Output: " & Output
Output = 0
Next b
Next a

GraphDataWS.Range("E2").Value = Output

End With

End Sub
```

Any other suggestions or comments are welcome, I'm still learning VBA/Excel. Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be VBA ? Looking at your image for the input and the expected result, I think you can just create a Pivot Table.

Comment: I could create a pivot table, but I'm looking to graph information from that. I'm actually porting the information from a table, so I'll look at that option today. If there's something that you could point me to cover that topic, it would be good. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm sorry as I can't understand this sentence :

> 1. to graph information from that
> 2. porting the information from a table

Anyway, other than create a pivot table from the data seen in your first image to get the expected result as seen in your second image ... I try to make the code based on the data seen in your first image to get the expected result as seen in you second image.

```
Sub test()
Dim rgdt As Range: Dim dateCol As Range: Dim cell As Range
Dim rgdt1 As String: Dim rgdt2 As String

Set rgdt = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
Set rgdt = rgdt.Resize(rgdt.Rows.Count - 1, rgdt.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
rgdt1 = "Sheet1!" & rgdt.Columns(1).Address
rgdt2 = "Sheet1!" & rgdt.Columns(2).Address

With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    .Value = "NAME"
    rgdt.Copy Destination:=.Offset(1, 0)
    .Range(rgdt.Columns(1).Address).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    .Range(rgdt.Columns(2).Address).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Set dateCol = .Range(rgdt.Columns(2).Address).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
    dateCol.Copy
    .Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    dateCol.Clear
    
    For Each cell In .Range(rgdt.Columns(1).Address).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
    With cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, dateCol.Rows.Count)
        .Value = "=countifs(" & rgdt1 & "," & cell.Address & "," & rgdt2 & ",B$1)"
        .Value = .Value
        .Replace What:=0, Replacement:="", MatchCase:=True
    End With
    Next

End With

End Sub
```

The sub assumed that there is nothing else in "Sheet1" but the data seen in your example  data image.

First it create rgdt variable as the range of the data in "Sheet1" (sheet "Data" in your case, so change accordingly) without including the header.

Then it create rgdt1 and rgdt2 string variable to point which sheet and which column of rgdt.

Then it prepares the "skeleton" of expected result in "Sheet2" (Sheet "Graph Data" in your case):

- fill cell A1 with "NAME"
- copy the rgdt to cell A1.offset(1,0)
- remove duplicate value in column A
- remove duplicate value in column B
- set the range of column B with data as dateCol variable (without the header)
- copy the dateCol and paste transpose to cell A1.offset(0,1)
- clear the value in dateCol

Next, it populate the value for the expected count result by looping to each cell which has value in column A, where on each loop it fill the range of cells after the looped cell to the right with COUNTIFS formula, remove the formula as value, then replace zero (0) result with nothing.

If you want to test the sub, create a new workbook, copy your data into cell A1 of "Sheet1", copy also the sub, then run the sub. See the expected result in "Sheet2".

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for the in depth response and explanation!